# Karate is testing deleted feature

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, karate

I was writing a test in Karate in VS Code, at some point I made a mistake and afterwards reverted it but when I was running the 'mvn test' command it was still running the wrong version of the code. I decided to delete the feature alltogether but it is still being tested and shown in test results even though the file no longer exists. Is this some issue with cache? If so, anybody knows how can I solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the contents of your `target` folder or try a ["clean"](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#clean)

```
karate -C
```